# Strange occurrence with one specific website

Tags: windows-xp, dns, webserver

A few people I know frequent a specific website.  All of us have different ISPs.

For some of us, it works perfectly normal.

For others, the site will time out at least once every half hour.  It will then be dead for between 5 and 30 minutes and will come back online.  However, it will also come back online immediately if you reboot.

Initially I thought maybe the DNS server was going down, but not everyone had the same experience.

Can someone with a better working knowledge of servers shed some light on potential issues that would cause this functionality?  All I know for sure is that I'm using WinXP.  Not sure of the other users, or the web server housing the site we're trying to use.

Comment: If it works reliably after a boot, it is not a network problem, it's something on you machine.

Comment: Can you reproduce the same problem on two machines? If so, if you reboot only one of the machines, does the other get back to the site while the other remains unable to connect? The reboot might be a red herring (in the few minutes it takes to reboot, the server becomes "ready to go"). The server may have a "connection limit". If the problem occurs, try disconnect all other machines and then see if it goes away.